# Word for different style of sport

Tags: sports

In basketball, you can actively block your opponent's shot. You can get in your opponent's way, and impede his progress actively.

In golf, you and your opponent perform independently of each other. I.e. You can't legally run up and "block" a swing (though that'd be funny if you did). Then, at the end, whoever did the best revealed.

I'm wondering if there's a word representing these two different types of sports. If I can't find a word, I'll describe one as an antagonistic sport (i.e. an antagonist actively combatting you) and the other as an independent sport.

Comment: How about **head-to-head** vs **side-by-side**?

Comment: Contact and non-contact

Comment: Games like basketball and boxing are adversarial and antagonistic, where offensive and defensive actions happen simultaneously, and tactics must be adjusted in real time. Games like golf and chess are sequential, where actions are taken one at a time, in sequence. Note that in games like golf, the actions of one player do not directly influence the actions of the other, in games like chess, the actions of one player do directly influence the actions of the other. I would be interested to learn what category names are formally or generally accepted in the field(s).